# Negating a regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How do I negate the regex `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*`? i.e. from a string '`12-mar-14, 21, 123_4, Value123, USER, 12/2/13'` I need to match values anything other than `Value123` and `USER`. Can someone please explain how?

I'm trying to replace the string '`12-mar-14, 21, 123_4, Value123, USER, 12/2/13'` to `'%Value123%USER%'` in Java. Anything that doesn't match `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*` should be replaced with `%`

A regex that would give following outputs for corresponding inputs.

Input: '`12-mar-14, 21, 123_4, Value123, USER, 12/2/13'`

Output: `'%Value123%USER%'`

Input: `'12-mar-14, 21, 123_4'`

Output: `'%'`

Input: `'New, 12-Mar-14, 123, dat_123, Data123'`

Output: `'%New%Data123%'`

Comment: What is the context? What language?

Comment: Explained my requirement a bit.

Comment: Why isn't `mar` kept? It matches `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*`

Comment: mar is followed by a '-'. I thought that wouldn't match `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*`. I think I must be wrong.

Comment: '[[0-9]+-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-[0-9]+]*|`[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*`|$|^' - The highlighted is the part I'm trying to negate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method:

```
//********** MODIFIED *************//
public static void getSentence(String line) {
    String text[] = line.split(",");
    String res = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        String word = text[i].trim();
        if (word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*")){
            if (!"".equals(res)) 
                res = res + "%";
            res = res + word;
        }
    }
    if ("".equals(res)) 
        res = "%";
    else
        res = "%" + res + "%";
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

...

```
this.getSentence("New, 12-Mar-14, 123, dat_123, Data123");
this.getSentence("12-mar-14, 21, 123_4, Value123, USER, 12/2/13");
```

Output:

```
%New%Data123%
%Value123%USER%
```

Comment: Value123 and USER are for illustration. If the input is '123,12-Mar-14' Output needs to be '%' and if input is  '123,12-Mar-14,newValue', output needs to be '%newValue%'

Comment: With 123,12-Mar-14 there isn't matches. So... I don't kwon if I understand you!! You don't need that output??
Output: %Value123%USER%

Comment: Added few more illustrations.

Comment: Use that method @zephyrus (answer modified!!)

Comment: This method works perfectly. But I have the same doubt, now, as @M42. `'Mar'` and `'mar'` matches `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*`. But it doesn't show up in the output. How is that?

Comment: @zephyrus because with "[a-zA-Z]+" only get matches if text contains alphabetic characters (from 'a' to 'z' or from 'A' to 'Z'). This not include others characters ('.', ',', ':', etc). ONLY ALPHABETIC!!
That '-' in the pattern means "FROM a TO z" and "FROM A TO Z".